# How to Display Text in new row in the TextView when you press the button

Tags: android

Goal:
when you press the button a new line with new text should be displayed in textview.

Problem:
Based on source code it is not working in order to fulfill the goal.

What part am I missing?

Info:
*I'm new in android
*I'm using API 23

---

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.jfdimarzio.netvork">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

---

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.jfdimarzio.netvork.MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_send"
        android:layout_width="349dp"
        android:layout_height="54dp"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/edittxt_input"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
        android:onClick="inputData"
        android:text="Send"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="441dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edittxt_input"
        android:layout_width="348dp"
        android:layout_height="39dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/btn_send"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/txtview_display"
        android:layout_marginBottom="19dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="392dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtview_display"
        android:layout_width="348dp"
        android:layout_height="355dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="16dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

---

```
package com.jfdimarzio.netvork;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import static com.jfdimarzio.netvork.R.id.txtview_display;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }


    public void inputData(View view)
    {
        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittxt_input);
        String message = editText.getText().toString();

        TextView myTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtview_display);

        myTextView.setText(message + "\n");
    }

}
```

Comment: What issue are you facing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to display the content of *editText* in a new line along with the previous text. If so, you may change the function *inputData()* like this:

```
public void inputData(View view) {
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittxt_input);
    String message = editText.getText().toString();

    TextView myTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtview_display);
    String oldText = myTextView.getText();

    myTextView.setText(oldText + "\n" + message);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually when you want setText right now from the activity , you have to refresh Activity  and after that is not work becouse the string not saved by SharedPreferences. or you can create a method like this and add [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private String message;
    private TextView myTextView;
    private EditText editText;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        myTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtview_display);
        editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittxt_input);

    }


    public void inputData(View view) {

        message = editText.getText().toString().trim();

        if (!message .isEmpty()){
            MethodName(message);
        }
    }

    public void MethodName(String message){
        myTextView.setText(message + "\n");
    }

}
```